# What are fast and safe options to setup a VPN between the office and GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

**Aim:** to setup a VPN between GCP (Google Cloud Platform) and the office

---

Create VPN connection

[image]

Create a VPN connection

[image]

**Idea**

We are now considering to setup [StrongSwan](https://www.strongswan.org/), but wonder if this will work from a random system within the office or is a public IP required?

The idea we have now is to create a VM in Digital Ocean (DO), configure a StrongSwan server, enter the IP to the GCP network UI and then let the desktops connect to the DO VM? Is this a safe and the fast way to configure a VPN between the office and GCP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud VPN makes it easy to configure a IPsec site-to-site VPN tunnel between GCP and your local network. In order to configure the tunnel you need to have a VPN gateway on your local network with public IP that will connect to the Cloud VPN. The only scenario supported right now is IPsec gateway-to-gateway as mentioned on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/overview#when_to_use_cloud_vpn):

> Cloud VPN only supports IPsec gateway-to-gateway scenarios. You must have a dedicated physical or virtual IPsec VPN gateway on the client side. Cloud VPN does not currently support client-to-gateway (road warrior) scenarios. In other words, it doesn't work with client software on a laptop, only with full IPsec VPN gateway software. Cloud VPN does not support VPN technologies other than IPsec.

In case you are looking for client-to-gateway scenario you can install and configure VPN software like Strongswan on a GCE VM as a server and VPN clients can connect to this VPN server. You can refer to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/6Azm-yr2x7Y) thread where similar scenarios was discussed.